# Detect touches which started outside of view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to detect touches when the gesture started outside of the current view?

Example:
I have a small view where I detect touches.
User starte moving finger on screen, starting outside of by view and then enters it without lifting finger.
When finger enters view, the view does not get any touch events.

Answer (score 1):

Override `pointInside:withEvent:` in your view and that should do it, though the point has to be within the parent view and the child view has to be visible and have user interaction enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that this solves it... Which view should have this?The child or the parent?

Comment: The child view - it would return YES for coordinates anywhere in the area it's supposed to be able to detect touches from. (to start out you could just return YES all the time and see the view starts receiving touch events - makes sure you've got userInteractionEnabled on)

Comment: I still don't see that this solves the problem where the finger moves over to another view without being lifted - the new view doesn't start to respond to events.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that was the problem - in that case you'd probably want some sort of transparent overlay that sent messages to different views as the finger moved along in it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a method that you can add a custom transparent UIButton, which cover all screen. And any touch outside of another view will trigger this UIButton event.

Comment: I am looking at the scenario where the touch is continuous - started outside and dragged into a view.

Comment: I have a idea. Can you use a custom view which cover all screen and be in the background, let the custom view be responsible all touches event, and monitor the touch entering the target views which above the custom view.

Comment: When the touch is entering to the target view, the custom view can redirect the touches event to the target view with the tochesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent: and touchesEnded:withEvent messages.